# Experience using Strobe Media Playback (OSMF)?

Tags: flash, osmf

Does anyone have an experience of using [Strobe Media Playback](http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/index.php) (OSMF) in a real project?

How is it compared to **JW Player** and **Flowplayer**?

Any answers are kindly accepted.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSMF helps in standardizing and streamlining development for media delivery and will , as a framework , hide all the details from you the developer and give you a set of tools to simplify your task.

Also , OSMF aim at using the same tools whether you're dealing with video, audio & images. So on one hand , you have a simplified approach to develop your own video solution but on the other hand you can broaden this approach and use OSMF for all types of media.

It seems OSMF will get a lot of support, Flash is widely used for video delivery and media delivery, so the idea of a standardized approach has been welcomed by the community.

Strobe Media Playback is an implementation of OSMF , since Adobe is behind it , it may mean that they would want it to become a standard for video delivery in Flash. Of course JWP & FP have been around for quite some time, but my guess is SMP may come as a strong contender... Just a guess :)

Comment: How do you think the current situation is? Has OSMF become a strong contender?

Answer (score 1):

I definitely love BSD license in Strobe player.

It definitely seems like that's gonna become new standard flash player.
With Adobe behind it - I'd personally rather use that's free, open-source, no strings attached and directly from manufacturer.

Seems like no brainer to me.

Though - Strobe's docs are totally scattered all over the place....

Answer (score 1):

This is now a very old post so I thought it would be good to revive it since a lot have changed the last 4 years.

**StrobeMediaPlayback** is no longer being maintained so the project has stranded. It is completely based on OSMF and can only be used on the Adobe Flash platform. You will probably have to use it in combination with another html5 player. OSMF has no html5 fallback. In my experience a lot of development is needed if you want to use it professionally. It is true that there are a lot of osmf plugins out there, but the default skin it comes with will probably need to be changed. And that will probably cost you between 2-6 months of work depending on what you need.

**Flowplayer** and **JW Player** is still actively being developed. My personal view is that JW Player is the strongest of the three when you compare feature set and so on, but JW Player is also a commercial player and it will cost you if you want to use it professionally. Flowplayer on the other hand has a GLP v3 license. So it is possible to use it free of charge. Please keep in mind though that you probably will end up spending quite a bit of time developing your final solution if you need it for a professional site. So the amount of resources you have to spend on Flowplayer more then defends buying a JW Player license. Both of these players comes in html5 with a flash fallback.

I have been maintaining a StrobeMediaPlayback custom flash/html5 player now for the last 2 years and although it has been fun, it has also cost us somewhere between 1200 and 2000 hours of development and maintenance only during the last two years. Multiply that with your hourly consultancy fee and you have a hefty sum.

It is no longer the case that you necessarily need to have a flash fallback though. You might as well go for a html5 player with the current browser support for html5 and the Media Source API. This means that there is no reason to choose StrobeMediaPlayback. You also don't need neither Flowplayer or JW Player. There are a lot of other html5 players out there.

If you want to use as little time as possible figuring out how things works, then I would go with JW Player. Development time costs money and JW player minimize that significantly.

If the license that JW Player doesn't go well with your business model and you can ignore the 2% users that still only can use flash, then I would go for a pure html5 video player.

**Support for Media Source API**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource

**IE usage**: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

**Firefox usage**: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_firefox.asp

**Here is a crude comparison of html5 video players. You might find other comparisons out there that is better**: http://html5video.org/wiki/HTML5_Video_Player_Comparison