# Strobe Media Playback vs Flowplayer

Tags: flowplayer, osmf

This question has already been asked in [Experience using Strobe Media Playback (OSMF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691330/experience-using-strobe-media-playback-osmf) but that was way back in 2010.

Can anyone help me understand the current situation? I want to integrate a video player but am confused if i have to use OSMF or Flowplayer. Can anyone give me suggestions or pros/cons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience the best part of Flowplayer is you can easily branded into different style which essentially you can customize the player at almost everywhere. It supports both css pre-defined style or dynamic update with JavaScript which will be extremely handy if you need to some advanced task. On this aspect, however, OSMF doesn't give you too many flexibility.